# Link list program crash on malloc

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc

I'm fairly new to C and coding in general so please bear with me. I've been trying to implement a linked list recently and this is the code i came up with

```
typedef struct something{
    int data;
    struct something *next;
} thing ;

int main ()
{
thing *head, *current;

head=malloc(sizeof(thing));
puts("head=malloc(sizeof(thing));");

if (head != NULL)
    puts("malloc success");

head=NULL;

current=head;
puts("current=head;");
if (current == NULL)
    puts("current is NULL");


puts("while");
while (current!=NULL)
{
    current = current->next;
}
puts("end while");


current->next=malloc(sizeof(thing));
puts("current->next=malloc(sizeof(thing));");

//free at end of program
}
```

While the compiler shows 0 errors, when i run the program it only runs until the final `malloc` part before crashing. It doesnt run the final `puts` so i will assume it's something to do with the way i'm trying to use malloc.
I'll gladly appreaciate for someone to tell me what im doing wrong.

Comment: The `while` loop ends when `current == NULL`. So `current->next` will fail because  `current` doesn't point to anything.

Comment: Please read this: [ask]. You need to post a [mcve]

Comment: Also, you never initialize `head->next` to `NULL` when you first allocate it.

Comment: why do you do this : `head=NULL;` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `while` loop goes to far. You want to stop when `current` points to the last element of the list, so you can add to it. But you're going one step further, and stopping when `current == NULL`. It's then too late to assign to `current->next`.

First, you need to initialize `head->next` to NULL.

```
head = malloc(sizeof(thing));
head->next = NULL;
```

Get rid of the line:

```
head = NULL;
```

as this is overwriting the result of `malloc()`.

Then your while loop needs to test `current->next`, not `current` itself:

```
while (current->next != NULL) {
    current = current->next;
}
```

And when you add the new node, you have to set its `next` pointer to `NULL` as well:

```
current->next = malloc(sizeof(thing));
current->next->next = NULL;
```

These should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks so much for this explanation. It seems i was misunderstanding the point of setting to NULL. Again, thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

You allocate `head` and then immediately after few checks point its pointer to `NULL`

```
// Allocation here

head=malloc(sizeof(thing));
puts("head=malloc(sizeof(thing));");

// Not a null 
if (head != NULL)
    puts("malloc success");

// Point to NULL again ???
head=NULL;
```

Then your `current` points to `head` viz `NULL` again that makes `current` `NULL`

```
current=head;
puts("current=head;");
if (current == NULL)
    puts("current is NULL");
```

and then you dereference `current` and try to `malloc`

```
puts("while");
while (current!=NULL)
{
    current = current->next;
}
puts("end while");


current->next=malloc(sizeof(thing)); //current is NULL here NULL->next is invalid
puts("current->next=malloc(sizeof(thing));");
```